# Installing Ethernet Card driver while inside Live CD

Tags: wireless, drivers, live-cd

I want to install rtl8723au Ethernet driver before actually installing OS, so that i would have access to the internet in the process(wi-fi is the only option). I have all the files i need for that, but i don't know how to actually access them while i'm inside the Live CD. Is there a way to include it (the folder with the driver) somehow into the Live CD and install it from there, or preinstall it into ISO image?

I need to be able to execute the following commands for drivers to be installed:

> make
>
> sudo make install
>
> sudo modprobe 8723au

Also, one additional question, if i somehow don't have "make" preinstalled, how can i install it without internet connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(rtl8723au is not an Ethernet driver, but a wireless network adapter driver.)

While you could do complicated things just to get a network connection during the installation process, I suggest to drop that idea and just proceed without network connection. Then, after the installation has finished, boot your fresh installation, install the driver and update packages. This has the same result.

If you would like to have a network connectiong during the installation that requires that driver, you could open a terminal and invoke the commands. Note that a kernel module requires more than just `make`, you will also need kernel headers matching the target kernel (`linux-headers-3....-generic`) and a compiler (`gcc`). The compiler and make are installed with the `build-essential` package. For offline package installation, see [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/974/6969)

When booting the Live CD, chose for *Try* instead of *Install*. You will then start a graphical desktop where you can look for the Terminal application to invoke the commands. If you have a USB, you could then also use the graphical file browser to find out.

Be also aware that manually installing a driver module like that will break every time you update your kernel. To avoid that trouble, you could DKMS to rebuild your module at every update, and/ or file a feature request at the Ubuntu Bugtracker (Launchpad) for driver inclusion (if it was not already available).

The `linux-image-extra-3.13.0-30-generic` package ships with the rtl8723ae module which should support built-in PCIe cards, so maybe you do not have to go through that trouble of manually installing a driver. Note the `e` suffix for PCIe, you mentioned the rtl8723au module which exists for USB devices, but maybe that was a typo?